# Не запускается ChatterBot python

Tags: python

Я хочу написать голосового помощника на python. Я хотел сделать так чтобы с ним можно было просто поболтать, как с Яндекс Алисой. Решил воспользоваться библиотекой ChatterBot и использовать датасет от Ubuntu (UbuntuCorpusTrainer). Для проверки скопировал скрипт из документации на github:

```
import logging
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import UbuntuCorpusTrainer

# Enable info level logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

chatbot = ChatBot('Jarvis')

trainer = UbuntuCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

# Start by training our bot with the Ubuntu corpus data
trainer.train()

# Now let's get a response to a greeting
response = chatbot.get_response('Привет')
print(response)
```

Но есть проблема - он выводит ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Chat-bot.py", line 23, in <module>
    chatbot = ChatBot(speech_to_text.code_word[0])
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chatterbot/utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chatterbot/storage/storage_adapter.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.tagger = Tagger(language=kwargs.get(
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 20, in __init__
    import spacy
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/pipeline/attributeruler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .pipe import Pipe
  File "spacy/pipeline/pipe.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipe
  File "spacy/vocab.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.vocab
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/tokens/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .doc import Doc
  File "spacy/tokens/doc.pyx", line 36, in init spacy.tokens.doc
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spacy/schemas.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pydantic import StrictStr, StrictInt, StrictFloat, StrictBool, ConstrainedStr
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConstrainedStr' from 'pydantic' (/home/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно сделать или посоветуйте другой способ как можно сделать это.

Comment: А какая версия питона нужна? Может либы на 3.10 не работают эти

Comment: У меня 3.10, сейчас попробую поменять и проверю. Ещё есть проблема что в папке pydantic вообще нет ни одного упоминания о ConstrainedStr

Comment: В документации написано 3.6. И ещё я не знаю как поменять версию(((. Я пользуюсь линуксом и pycharm